# The difference between DN500K and DN520K?

Tags: electric-guitar

I'm looking into buying my first real "metal" guitar(yay), and thought the Ibanez Darkstone series would fit the perfect description.

I'm having troubles finding the difference between the 2010 and 2009 models though, of which is better or worse. They both have the same pickups, dimensions and quality. The only thing I can find a real difference in is the price and colours.

I have trolled Google and Ibanez's website for an answer, but they don't hold any useful information.
Can anybody perhaps tell me the difference between the two of them? Because I'm not seeing myself pay extra just for a the model's year.

Answer (score 3):

Only difference seems to be the color options/types the newer model has some Semi-Transparent Colors; a Dark Violet and a Silver Burst.
Unless color is a big deal to you I'd just go for the cheapest model.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there were any major differences. Look at [this page](http://www.ibanez.co.jp/ShowcaseModel2011/Darkstone/C01.html) for some Darkstone history.

However if you want one that will be really special - the new DN2011SC-BKC is a lovely looking thing!

[image]

Comment: At about 1,750 bucks more. I saw that one though, and also have to admit that it is beautiful. :)

Comment: Pretty sweet ride for you metal heads out there :D

Comment: It has to be on my list @Jduv, however I'm currently saving for the NS/Stick - http://www.stick.com/instruments/ns/ - one of Chapman's creations.  Mmmmmmm